# System error has occured on 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xorg

Almost every minute, my pc pops out error `System error has occured`.
This happens every boot and after typing password.
In HP Screen i get some moving and flicking -´s and on ubuntu boot screen
My specs are:

```
AMD Athlon II X2 220 @ 2,8 GHz
4 GB DDR3 SDRAM
NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT 512 MB (PNY)
450W PSU
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
7200 RPM 500 GB HDD
```

Logs:

```
Dec 24 11:09:06 otto-G5239sc-m rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="865" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Dec 24 11:09:22 otto-G5239sc-m anacron[869]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Dec 24 11:09:22 otto-G5239sc-m anacron[869]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Dec 24 11:11:07 otto-G5239sc-m com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Applications[1617]: Error loading package indexes: Couldn't stat '/var/cache/software-center/xapian'
Dec 24 11:11:07 otto-G5239sc-m com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Applications[1617]: (unity-scope-loader:2720): unity-applications-daemon-CRITICAL **: daemon.vala:144: Failed to load Software Center index. 'Apps Available for Download' will not be listed
Dec 24 11:14:07 otto-G5239sc-m snapd[908]: 2017/12/24 11:14:07.428920 snapmgr.go:415: No snaps to auto-refresh found
Dec 24 11:17:01 otto-G5239sc-m CRON[2811]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 24 11:18:59 otto-G5239sc-m systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Dec 24 11:18:59 otto-G5239sc-m systemd-tmpfiles[2843]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
Dec 24 11:18:59 otto-G5239sc-m systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.

driver 0
```

I am very sick of this, my pc is hp g5239sc-m 
Monitor: HP S2031A
Any solution for me? as i am out of luck with pc

Answer (score -1):

Oh yes, you can use the nouveau driver, first delete nvidia, than the nouveau driver keeps left but unfortunately I discovered that games like pinball Emilia do not work anymore, I don't know why since nouveau has opengl.